# How to access fedex shipping method values

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping, sales, fedex

In magento a`dmin -> system -> configuration -> sales -> shipping methods -> FedEx`

in this we save Meter Number and other details.

How to access these values directly? and where these values store in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these values store in `core_config_data` database table and accessing these value directly using `Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/fedex/account');` where value in bracket correspond to value in `path`column of database table above mentioned